# Dual monitor: Set the external monitor as main display but external monitor not working

Tags: windows-10, display

I was using an external monitor to extend my display in Windows 10, along with my default laptop screen.

Somehow I marked the external monitor as the "Main Display", now due to resolution issue, I only see a black screen and "Monitor out of range" written on it when I extend the display.

My laptop's screen is not able to open the "Display Settings" as it is not the main monitor.

I tried connecting another external display and making the laptop screen as the main monitor, but as it turns out, Windows remembers monitors.

How do I make the laptop screen as the "Main Screen", any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `Right Click` anywhere on the laptop screen and select **Display Settings**.

This will make it "Load" on the main screen.

In order to move it to your laptop. Hold the `Windows Key + Shift` keys and then press the `Left` or `Right` arrow keys until you see the settings on your laptop's screen.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Also `Windows Key` + `P` should open the settings on both screens.